# Where to see a FULL Day9 casts list that is updated daily?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have tried but cannot find a Day9 casts list that includes all of his casts. There's [one on Team Liquid](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=104154), but it doesn't seem like all of them.

In particular, I am looking for the cast where Sean is talking about macro during micro.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try http://day9tv.blip.tv/posts?view=archive. This is his main archive; this is the best source of vids.

The one I think you are referring to is [Day[9] Daily #252 - Secrets of Hotkeys, APM and Mouse Movement](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/4712303/)

Comment: He also uploads his videos to [his youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/day9tv). These are done by Sean himself, so they go up later than the blip.tv ones.